# Trouble with basic mySql procedure

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_cpsc408db |
+---------------------+
| Product             |
| laptop              |
| pc                  |
| printer             |
+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create procedure hello()
    -> begin
    -> select * from product;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
mysql>
```

I am not sure what is causing this syntax error, and haven't had any success so far figuring it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the DELIMITER keyword:

This is so MySQL can tell which statements are within the procedure and where the end of the procedure declaration itself is

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE hello()
BEGIN
    select * from product;
END//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a delimiter otherwise the console does not know when you are finished:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE hello()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM product;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Read more about it here: [Getting Started with MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed, I will check out that tutorial.